# Flutter Single Child Scroll View with each item in column taking up 1/3 of the parent's height

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design

I'm trying to create 3-to-many widgets that take of 1/3 of the parent's space and is scrollable. I've tried to use the FractionallySizedBox to take of 1/3 of the parent's available space, however, when I put it in the SingleChildScrollView it throws the error:

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#6dc20 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
SingleChildScrollView

Here's my attempt

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: Container(height: 100, child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
              FractionallySizedBox(heightFactor: 1 / 3, child: Text("Text"),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish with HTML and CSS

```html
<style>
        .container {
          height: 200px;
          overflow: scroll;
        }
        .box {
          height: 33%
        }
      </style>

      <div class="container">
          <div class="box" style="background-color: red"></div>
          <div class="box" style="background-color: blue"></div>
          <div class="box" style="background-color: green"></div>
          <div class="box" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try Wrap your FractionallySizedBox with `Expanded` Widget

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, it still throws an render exception.

Comment: Try delete your container height

Comment: Removing container height will ruin what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

I understood your requirement and modified suggestion.
Each item's height is 200/3 in 200 height container and scrollable.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 200,
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    Container(
                      height: viewportConstraints.maxHeight / 3,
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
                      child: Text("Text$i"),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm gonna play with the ConstrainedBox, but I expect the fourth text to be hidden and need to be scroll to because each widget takes up 1/3 of the 200 space.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `FractionallySizedBox` in Flexible as shown in the [short_video_by_flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html) when working with `Row` or `Column`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: Container(height: 100, child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
              Flexible(
                  child: FractionallySizedBox( 
                             heightFactor: 1 / 3,  
                             child: Text("Text"),
                         ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, however, it stills throws an render exception.

Comment: Try inseting `Container` inside `SingleChildScrollView`